# How can I enable stripe to production mode in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

I do not understand where i can enable the production mode to stripe because it's in test mode:

```
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY=xxx
STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY=xxx

STRIPE_SECRET_KEY_PROD=xxx
STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY_PROD=xxx
```

I have to change it in the stripe dashboard? or where? i did not do this app i'm reading it and it already had in the .env the two keys, i tried deleting the test one but it did not work, it started to show me that it needed an api key.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change it in the stripe panel. Once you switched to production mode, you will get new keys which is for the production mode.

By Default you will only see the sandbox key details there in stripe under the api keys section

[Stripe Account Keys](https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys)

[image]

Under the stripe dashboard you will see a side menu like above image there you can see a radio button mentioning, `Viewing test data` which needs to be enabled to changed to live mode.

After enabling the live mode, go to the [Stripe Account Keys](https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys) (stripe account keys page) to get the live keys.